# Bootstrap modal not hiding and showing when and how it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to javascript and I am trying to do some javascript client-side validation for my web form. I have a bootstrap modal that is supposed to pop up after a button has been clicked. If the required fields == " ", I want to hide the modal, but if they have some data, I want to show the modal.

This is how I import my bootstrap and jquery libraries

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My javascript code

```
function CheckRequired() {

        var crn = document.getElementById("txtCRN").value;
        var subject = document.getElementById("ddlExistingSubjects").value;
        var courseNo = document.getElementById("txtCourseNumber").value;
        var section = document.getElementById("txtSection").value;
        var creditHours = document.getElementById("txtCreditHours").value;
        var courseName = document.getElementById("txtCourseName").value;
        var startDate = document.getElementById("StartDate").value;
        var endDate = document.getElementById("EndDate").value;
        var meetingTime = document.getElementById("txtMeetingTime").value;
        var firstName = document.getElementById("txtPrimaryFirstName").value;
        var lastName = document.getElementById("txtPrimaryLastName").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("txtPrimaryEmail").value;

        if (crn == "" || subject == "" || courseNo == "" || section == "" || creditHours == "" || courseName == "" ||
            startDate == "" || endDate == "" || meetingTime == "" || firstName == "" || lastName == "" || email == "") {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#addCourseModal').modal('hide')
            });
        }
        else {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#addCourseModal').modal('show')
            });
        }
    }
```

Bootstrap modal and button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-md" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCourseModal" id="btnAddCourse" onclick="CheckRequired();">Add Course</button>
```

The modal still shows when all those fields specified in the javascript code are empty and doesn't show when they are not empty.

This is what a required field looks like in my code, I am using HTML5 required attribute for validation as well.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCRN" runat="server" class="form-control" type="number" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
```

Please help. Thanks.

P.S, I am coding in C# ASP.NET

Comment: Instead of `document.getElementById()` and `value` you can use `$()` and `.val()` - also for best practice in coding: it looks like you want to have an action called when all inputs are not filled in? so you can get all inputs at once with `$('input')` ?

Comment: can you post your html to go with your js codes for practical purposes?